# ASP.NET SignalR not sending messages to client

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I realize there are breaking changes between SignalR and ASP.NET SignalR and I changed my code to accommodate that. But for some reason, I'm not able to figure out the right change.

The issue I'm having is that the server is not sending messages to the client.

***Old SignalR code:***

**Server**

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Dashboard>();
var subscribers = context.Clients;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Source))
{
    var subscriber = subscribers[message.Source];

    subscriber.messageReceived(message);
}
```

**Client**

```
$.connection.dashboard.messageReceived = function(){...};
```

***New code (ASP.NET SignalR):***

**Server**

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Dashboard>();
var subscribers = context.Clients;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Source))
{
    var subscriber = subscribers.Group(message.Source);             
    subscriber.messageReceived(message);
}
```

**Client**

```
$.connection.dashboard.client.messageReceived = function(){...};
```

Can someone help me figure out what's going wrong here?

Comment: I'm hoping this logic isn't in the hub:

var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Dashboard>();
var subscribers = context.Clients;

Comment: @dfowler: Its in a static method in the Hub: `public static void Publish(DashboardMessage message)`. Along with publish, this static method also caches the message to keep the last good copy around. I ignored these details for brevity. But I'd love to hear your thoughts around it.

Comment: You may want to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531314/signalr-groups-not-getting-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your code logic to work.  Here's what I built off your logic:

SERVER:

```
public class Status : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foo");
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public void foo()
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Status>();
        var subscribers = context.Clients;
        var subscriber = subscribers.Group("foo");
        subscriber.messageReceived("ello");
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
var status = $.connection.status;

status.client.messageReceived = function (val) {
    alert(val);
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    status.server.foo();
});
```

My only thoughts onto why your implementation is not working is:

1. You are not adding the connection ID to the group that you're trying to broadcast to (see my OnConnected function on the server).
2. In your .client method for messageReceived you are not allowing for a value to be passed as a paramter.  Unless you're parsing the arguments object within the function you will not be able to get the message value.
3. Your message.Source is incorrect

Hope this helps!

Comment: #1 - I'm doing that actually: ` $.connection.dashboard.server.subscribe(self.subscribedSources)` and `Subscribe` does `foreach (var @group in sources)
                {
                    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, @group);
                }`  #2 - `client.messageReceived` does take in a parameter, I just omitted in the post thinking its not required for the discussion at least (my bad obviously).   #3 - Why do say that? I'm trying to publish messages to only subscribed source(s).

Comment: For #3 I was just saying "if your" message source is incorrect.  I'd debug the foreach logic and ensure that all the group namings are being saved/recalled correctly.

Comment: Well, it works in SignalR v0.5.3. Exact same lines of code (except for the publish part). Any idea if I'm missing an intermediate step somewhere with the new versions?

Comment: Aww you know what, with the new version do you have an App_Start folder (did Nuget install it for you?).  If so do you have a .cs file that calls .MapHubs?  In 0.5.3 you did not have to specfically call .MapHubs but in the latest prerelease you now have to.

Comment: I've a RegisterHubs.cs (its an MVC project) and it calls `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); ` via WebActivator. Should there be anythign else in there?